# Android ListView With Check Box Deleting/Getting Row ID

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to implement a listview with checkbox so that when a check box is checked the list row will be removed. I am populating the listview with a cursor and this is working fine and the checkbox is being displayed.

What I am having trouble with is figure out how to get the _id of the row of the box that has been checked.

Can anyone show me how to implement something like this

**ListView and CheckBox**

```
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllItems();

    //String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_NAME, db.KEY_CODE, db.KEY_ROWID};
    String[] columns = new String[] {db.KEY_ITEM_NAME, db.KEY_MEASUREMENT, db.KEY_UNIT};

    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.ingredientName, R.id.ingredientMeasurement, R.id.ingredientUnit};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.row4, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    final ListView shoppingList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingList);
    shoppingList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);


    CheckBox deleteCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    deleteCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (isChecked){
                // How do I get the list item clicked to delete row?
            }
        }

    });
```

**XML - Row.4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingredientName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:hint="wewewe"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingredientMeasurement"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredientName"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:hint="fefefef"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingredientUnit"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredientMeasurement"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:hint="qqqqq"/>


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, you can create two methods for removing items from listview, one in adapter and second in database.  `adapter.remove(item.getId(checkedId));` and calling second method from database `dataBase.remove(item.getId(checkedId));` That is how you will delete item from adapter and database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just one question, the `getId` function, will this get the `id` of the row or the actual `_id` in the database?

Comment: `getId` function will get the specified id of the object you are selecting in listView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this custom cursor adapter and handle onCheckedChanged here in this adapter.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cr;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cr = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(your column here);
        int columnvalue = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        checkBox1.setTag(columnvalue);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int id = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am slightly confused as to how to implement this into the list activity?

Comment: you are using SimpleCursorAdapter just replace it with this CustomAdapter, I hope it will work.

Comment: Also set values for ingredientName,ingredientMeasurement and ingredientUnit in bindView method and columnValue will be the id that you want to get when checkbox is checked.

Comment: I am trying to do a simple Toast in the onCheckChange method to see if the id is changing but it is staying the same no matter what what row is being pressed and I cant delete the specfic row, am I missing something for it to be changing for each row??

Comment: checkBox1.setTag(columnvalue); check this line what tag are setting here in bindView method, is it same or is changing.

Comment: I left it the same is in the code you gave, and set the line above as `int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");`

Comment: what's name here ? you have to set  the id of record you want to delete in setTag() and in onCheckedChanged getting the same tag.

Comment: Oh i see now, sorry I was confusing myself completely there, sorry for all the questions and thanks very much for the help!